# Splitting sequence of 1's and 0's into byte

Tags: java, file, compression, huffman-code

I am currently working on huffman decoding. I have a `String` representation of all the character encodings(i.e "1101000100000001"). I am trying to split it into groups of 8 and return its corresponding value(i.e. "11010001" would return 209). However it seems to not work with smaller files. Below is the code that I have. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
for(char bit : textbytes.toCharArray())
            {
                if(bit == '1')
                {
                    target |= 1 << bitCount;
                }
                bitCount++;
                if(bitCount >= 8)
                {
                    bitCount = 0;
                    bits.add(target);
                    target = 0;
                }
            }
            byte[] bitstring = new byte[bits.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < bits.size(); i ++)
            {
                bitstring[i] = bits.get(i);
                compressedFile.write(bitstring[i]);
            }
```

P.S. Some parts I took from the Internet so I do not fully understand it (such as `target |= 1<< bitCount`)

Comment: Any specific language preference?

Comment: I think you should pad it with 0s

Comment: hmm it seems to not work with smaller files either even though there are more than 8 1's and 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not trying to do huffman coding yet, just turn "binary" `String`s of `0` or `1` into Java integer types. Try this:

```
public static long decode(String textbytes) {
    long result=0;

    for(char ch : textbytes.toCharArray()) {
        result = result << 1;
        if(ch == '1')
            result = result + 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This method decodes bit strings into Java `long`s. There's no need to worry about breaking into chunks of 8 (unless this is homework, and that's part of the assignment). In particular, it handles the example you gave properly ("11010001" => 209).

The approach is pretty simple:

1. Start with `result = 0`
2. For each character in the input string, shift `result` 1 bit to the left to "make room" for the bit represented by the current character. Afterwards, add `1` to result if the current character represents a `1` bit.

Also, the code assumes you get no bit strings longer than 64 bits, which you may want to check for robustness.

Comment: If I am using FileInputStream read() method to read bytes then will it still not matter how many bits there are? I know the read() method reads in a byte of data so if "1101000100000001" is encoded entirely without being broken up, will it affect how read() works?

Comment: Because of the way I'm storing the data (in a `long`), this method only handles up to 64 bits. If you stored the data differently -- for example in a `BigInteger` like in another answer in this thread -- this method would handle as many bits as you could throw at it (memory permitting, of course). As long as you're sure that the only characters you'll read are either `'1'` or `'0'`, it makes no difference whether you read in characters or bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it differently

```
    byte[] bytes = new BigInteger("1101000100000001", 2).toByteArray();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
         compressedFile.write(b);
    }
```